# Session expiration management with Spring Session for a single page app

Tags: spring-session

I use **Spring Session** and I am having issues with session management especially dealing with session expiration.

The idea is to return a custom Http Header to the client e.g. `X-Application-Session-Is-New` if the session has expired.

Here is what I came up with:

```
public class SessionDestroyedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    //TODO: not always invoked!!
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isAjaxRequest(request) && (isRequestedSessionInvalid(request) || isSessionNew(request))) {
            response.addHeader("X-Application-Session-Is-New", "true");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isRequestedSessionInvalid(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
    }

    private boolean isSessionNew(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getSession(false).isNew();
    }

    private boolean isAjaxRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }
}
```

The issue is that my filter does not seem to be always invoked upon session expiration perhaps because the request is not an ajax request and a new session ID is immediately created after that.

Can anyone please point me to an appropriate strategy to deal with session expiration on single page apps?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Following is currently not possible (instead do decoration)
Here are some related github issues (comment on them to fix them faster)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/243

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/112

To accomplish this you have to use your own `HttpSessionStrategy`.

Here is an example if you are using `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` (the default one)

```java
public class CustomHttpSessionStrategy extends CookieHttpSessionStrategy {
    @Override
    public void onInvalidateSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.onInvalidateSession(request, response);
        response.addHeader("X-Application-Session-Is-New", "true");
    }
}
```

If you want to add your header on new sessions also consider overriding *onNewSession(Session, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)*.

Comment: Hi tsachev. eh eh. CookieHttpSessionStrategy is final :-(

Comment: Then you need to decorate it I guess. and please vote for this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/243 so they fix it.

Comment: Hi again Tsachev. Can you please explain how the HttpSessionStrategy is different to the Filter strategy?

Comment: Well in a filter the session might not yet be created, or the response may already be committed. Spring session repository filter creates a response wrapper and writes the cookie as late as possible, using http session strategy.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Wrong**

*Please see my other answer*

You should move your logic for adding `X-Application-Session-Is-New` after request is processed.
Try something like

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    if (isAjaxRequest(request) && (isRequestedSessionInvalid(request) || isSessionNew(request))) {
        response.addHeader("X-Application-Session-Is-New", "true");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tsachev. Can you please briefly explain why?

Comment: @balteo actually doing this in filter will always be wrong. either too early or too late. See my other answer.